# Set Image width using inline css

Tags: html, css

I want to set the width of Image. here is my code :-

```
<div style="width: 630px;">
        <img src="Image/welcomeimage.jpg" alt="no image" />
  </div>
```

Here is my situation, I don't have to set the width of Image. Only I can set the width of Div.
So I have to set the image width using div.
How can I do this?

[Edit]
Thanks to all for helping me. Now I solved my problem.
Initially, I was told not to use CSS, I had to solved this issue using Inline CSS.
But It was not possible. So I decided to use CSS.

Comment: why can't you set the image width?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the width of your image via the width of your div?

Comment: Whatever you do, you will not come around to set at minimum once styles for the img. If your image would have a width of 100%, then you could set the width with the div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use `max-width`

You can use the `max-width` property which [is supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh) in all modern browsers and IE 8 and above.

To use it call it in your css like so:

```
div img { max-width: 100%; }
```

This will stretch your image to the `div`'s width.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Also note that you will have to set `box-sizing` to `border-box` if your image has borders

Answer (score 4):

Just do this if you want to set the width inline:

```
<div>
    <img src="Image/welcomeimage.jpg" alt="no image" width="630" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. I never changed `img` explicitly.

```
<div class="test" style="width: 630px;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FIylGsy.jpg" alt="no image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test > *{
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fGRbD/)

Comment: Thanks sonu, but as I said I can't write anything for image.

Comment: @Jacob You tell he can use CSS and then give an example in javascript? I'm amazed.

Comment: @RajeshBiswas I misunderstood you. I thought you don't want to set any static width for `img`.

Comment: @RajeshBiswas Updated. Is this helpful now?

Answer (score 1):

Try in css file sth like this:

```
div img {
    width: 630px;
}
```

Can you use JavaScript (for example jQuery)?

Answer (score 0):

You can se the width of the image dynamically using Javascript:

Pseudo:

```
var div = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
var width = div.style.height;
yourImg.style.width = width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```